# python Selenium taking instance of webdriver

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instanceof

i defined two separate functions for opening url with selenium, and fetching data with selenium.
In my second function `driver` variable is unassignable because it stays local inside first function.
I do not know if it s logical to separate selenium activity in two separate ways, I use this method first time.
Any suggestions to take instance of webdriver and use it inside second function?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#reading from csv file url-s
def readCSV(path_csv):
    df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    return df

fileCSV=readCSV(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\urls.csv')
length_of_column_urls=fileCSV['linkamazon'].last_valid_index()

#going to urls 1-by-1
def goToUrl_Se():
    for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls + 1):
        xUrl = fileCSV.iloc[i, 1]
        print(xUrl,i)
        # going to url(a,amazn) via Selenium WebDriver
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.headless = False
        chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        # options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

        webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\AmznScrpBot\chromedriver.exe')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(xUrl)

    driver.quit()

#fetch-parse the data from url page
def parse_data():
    x_title=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h2/a/span')

goToUrl_Se()
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about passing parameters to your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you trying to parse data from each URL you opening in `goToUrl_Se()`. If so the better way is to put the parsing data code inside the loop used in `goToUrl_Se()` method.
Also, no need to define and create `driver` each time.
And you definitely have to improve your locators. Very long absolute XPaths are extremely fragile and breakable.
The following flow seems for me to be better.

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = Null

#reading from csv file url-s
def readCSV(path_csv):
    df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    return df

fileCSV=readCSV(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\urls.csv')
length_of_column_urls=fileCSV['linkamazon'].last_valid_index()

def create_driver():
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.headless = False
        chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        # options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

        webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\AmznScrpBot\chromedriver.exe')
        global driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

#going to urls 1-by-1
def goToUrl_Se():
    for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls + 1):
        xUrl = fileCSV.iloc[i, 1]
        print(xUrl,i)
        # going to url(a,amazn) via Selenium WebDriver
        driver.get(xUrl)
        x_title=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h2/a/span')
    driver.quit()

create_driver()
goToUrl_Se()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `driver` from your `create_driver()` function:

```
def create_drive():
   // ...
   return driver
```

and change your function to accept a parameter:

```
def parse_data(driver):
    // ...
```

Now you can get the driver with an assignment and pass it to your function:

```
driver = create_driver()
parse_data(driver)
```

I suggest you read more about return values and function parameters to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

In this structure you can call your second function `parse_data` within your first function `goToUrl_Se()` only.

like:

```
driver.get(xUrl)
somoething = parse_data()
```

and change `parse_data` for it to return something

if you want to call them both outside themselves, then you need to do 2 things:

1. parse_data should get driver as and argument`def parse_data(driver)`
2. you should not quit selenium within `goToUrl_Se()`

and if you want to do it as it really should be done, then just use OOP. If you still don't want to, then you'd better initiate `driver` name ouside any functions and use function to change it. For instance you can have a function that change driver's options only. But that's bad practice when one function does multiple things, like your  `goToUrl_Se()` one.